# Changing captions so that text is directly under "figure"

Tags: captions

I am wondering whether anyone can help me. I'm trying to make my figure caption one block instead of having my text offset in respect to "figure". [image: Right now it looks like this:]

The code I'm using right now to set the image is this: I suppose it is possible that some of my packages or settings are interfering with each other.

```
\documentclass[12pt,pagesize,twoside,DIV=12,headsepline=0.4pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}           

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,setspace,caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,format=plain,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced,skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,labelfont=it,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,font=doublespacing}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}   
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}     
        \automark[chapter]{chapter} 
        \ohead[]{\headmark}     
        \cfoot[]{}             
        \ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}        
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\normalcolor\bfseries}   
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\normalcolor\bfseries}       



\begin{document}    

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{winterhat}
\centering
\caption[Winter hat]{\href{https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/winter-hat-637a36cb74204c719883af7feb4b7c28?fbclid=IwAR2f8dF3RrEBaolJk0mBtSuPB0PvR2YwI6i9q4spDLZfd5EoCE1d9FiqMFY}{Winter hat - 3D model} by \href{https://sketchfab.com/stubbornfunkydonkey}{StubbornFunkyDonkey} is licensed under \href{https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/}{CC BY 4.0}. This model of a winter hat was put on every scan in order to conceal the hairline and parts of the ears.}
\label{fig:winterhat}
\vspace{-50pt}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

And here is the image:

[image: winterhat]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to small but complete document, which we can compile as it is. Regarding caption, it is below figure, however, somewhere in your document preamble you define showed caption style.

Comment: thank you Zarko, I hope it's ok now

Comment: `\documentclass` is still missing :-(

Comment: sorry, I added it

Comment: Add `format=plain` to your `\captionsetup` command.

Comment: @leandriis thank you! It worked

Answer (score 1):

Your caption appear exactly as is defined in used `\documentclass` , i.e. in the `scrbook`. You can overwrite default settings by use of `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` placed
after `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}`, however your attempts is uclear. See MWE below.

A MWE (I omitted all irrelevant packages):

```
\documentclass[12pt,pagesize,twoside,
               DIV=12,headsepline=0.4pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=plain, % <--- new
                      font=footnotesize, labelfont=it,
                      singlelinecheck=false}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for text filer

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{r}{0.5\linewidth}% explicit reserved space for wrapfigure
\vspace{-\baselineskip} % <--- move image for one line up
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} % image width is equal to 'wrapfigure' width
\caption{"Winter hat - 3D model" by StubbornFunkyDonkey is licensed under CC BY 4.0. This model of a winter hat was put on every scan in order to conceal the hairline and parts of the ears.}
\label{fig:winterhat}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you liked different caption style, change `captionsetup` accordingly. Now I set according to my taste :-).

Note: similar suggestion for `captionsetup` you can find in @ leandriis comment.